# How can I escape a Ruby string containing newlines (and possibly other special characters) to a valid shell variable value?

Tags: ruby, string, bash, escaping

I need to write a Ruby function which generates a correct Bash export statement given a variable name and the value it should be assigned to. My current attempt is

```
def export(variable, string)
  "export #{variable}=#{Shellwords.escape(string)}"
end
```

However, it doesn't behave quite as I expect. E.g.

```
[2] pry(main)> export("X", "a\nb")
"export X=a'\n'b"
```

and then

```
export X=a'\n'b
echo "$X"
```

in the shell gives

```
a\nb
```

instead of the desired

```
a
b
```

If it matters (I don't expect it to, but just in case) the statement will be written into a file which will be sourced later.

Comment: You need more than just escaping: `X=$'a\nb'`. See my answer here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48121/13796

Comment: @jordanm That's helpful, but my question is how to get it for an arbitrary Ruby string, not this specific one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're copy-pasting the auto-echoed string from `irb`, not the *value* of said string. The auto-echoing is showing you a Ruby string literal with Ruby escapes left in, so you get:

```
irb(main)> Shellwords.shellescape("a\nb")
=> "a'\n'b"
```

If you printed that string (e.g. with `puts`) to get its raw value (with the escapes printed as their real characters), e.g.

```
irb(main)> puts Shellwords.shellescape("a\nb")
a'
'b
=> nil
```

and copy-pasted that to make:

```bash
export X=a'
'b
echo "$X"
```

it would work just fine.

Similarly, writing `"export X=#{Shellwords.escape(string)}"` to a file (via `puts` or other actual I/O APIs that write the string's value, not its representation) for later use would work just fine, because that would be inserting the string's value, and the file would end up with a raw newline between the single-quotes, not `\n`.

Comment: Writing `export X=#{Shellwords.escape(string)}` to a file was actually what I tried, but then became concerned it wouldn't work :)

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov: Always painful when you second-guess yourself out of the correct solution. :-)